# 4 bit combinatorial incrementer circuit: output boolean expression

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

The Boolean expression for outputs(Y3,y2,y1,y0) in a 4 bit combinatorial incrementer(i.e. if 0000 is given the circuit gives 0001 as output.On giving 1111 it resets to 0000) is given as:

- y3 = x3^(x2x1x0);
- y2 = x2^(x1x0);
- y1 = x1^x0;
- y0 = ~x0.
  where x0,x1,x2,x3 are inputs with x3 MSB and X0 LSB

Can anyone provide the simplification steps to obtain the boolean expression of y3,y2(as in question)from the k map drawn from the 4 bit incrementer truth table?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. 1. Please give your question some format. 2. Use MathJax for expression. See here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. This makes formulas and expressions more readable. Btw. what is the relation between x2x1x0?

Comment: No one can. This is not "solve my homework" service. You show what you tried, where is the problem and why can't you solve it. Then we can help.

Comment: It's fairly obvious that the fourth statement is wrong.

Comment: @KarlKarlsom Thanks for the all your suggestions.I will work on it.

Comment: @DaveTweed I missed the tilde and yes I corrected it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am a newbie in stackexchange and thought this was a site just to help people rather than to PROVE those bossing around if am working on it or otherwise. Having a reputation of around 5K it would be nice if you could follow 'Be nice.Be respectful' policy.And sorry,your comment wasnt helpful.Thanks for nothing.

Comment: @JananiRangaraj So you have read the rules, at least one of them. Then you should know what kind of questions are answered here and what is requirements from the one who is asking. And obviously my comment did help, as you followed my guidance and posted the required information, which did make you question salvageable, that I am going to vote for reopening. You are welcome.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In that sense your comment, to an extent, really did.Nice knowing you and thanks :)

Comment: As this question is no longer in hold, you should edit it , and give the answer in answer section so that other could easily know what is the answer is. And also click the "right" sign so that your question will be marked as "answered" .

Comment: @Anklon I editted the question and added the answer in answer section. "Right" sign can be clicked only tomorrow.So, I will do it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, I did not make the largest possible grouping of minterms in K map and was not able to simplify further. By correct grouping of minterms, I was able to get the expressions simplified to required form.

[image: Solution: Truth table and K map of y3 and y2]